# Deriving the form of the metric on the Poincare half-plane in polar coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, differential-equations

This question relates specifically to problem 3.11 from Sean Carroll's book *Spacetime and Geometry*.

After having proven in the text that the Poincare half-plane is a maximally symmetric space and that the curvature is constant everywhere, we are asked to use this fact to find an expression for the metric of this space in polar coordinates,
$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = f(r)^2(\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2\mathrm{d}\theta^2).$$

I have computed the Christoffel symbols, the components of the Riemann tensor, the Ricci tensor, and from there the Ricci scalar.

I have arrived at the expression
$$R = -\frac{1}{f(r)^2}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}r^2}(\ln f(r)) + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r}(\ln f(r))\right).$$

This expression has to be equal to $-\frac{2}{a^2}$ everywhere, but I cannot seem to find any way to solve it (I even used Mathematica and just waited and waited).

I think that this form of the Ricci scalar is ok because taking the solution for this problem,
$$ f(r) = \frac{\sqrt{2}a}{1-r^2},$$
and plugging it in the above expression of the Ricci scalar does give me the desired result.

How should one go about solving the differential equation that one gets when the Ricci scalar is set to equal a constant?

Comment: Isn't this ultimately a mathematics question ("how do I solve this ODE?") rather than a physics question?

Comment: Also note that setting $R= - 2/a^2$ would give you a second-order ODE.  Normally you would need two boundary conditions to yield a unique result for this ODE; the desired form for $f(r)$ is one possible solution to the ODE but not the most general one.  If you know more information about the value of $f$ at special values, that might help Mathematica solve it for you.

Comment: I have posted it as a physics question since I could have done something wrong in deriving the expression for the Ricci scalar. Also, I thought there is something "hand-wavy" about solving it since it comes from a physics coursebook, where the focus is not on the mathematics.